# Privilege: edit community wiki posts

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki, privileges, privileges-page

Don't know if this is the right place to answer this question, but I'll try it:

I've now the "privilege to edit community posts"; moved by curiosity, [I opened the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) to understand what exactly they are, and the first paragraph says:

> What are Community Wiki posts?
>
> Community wiki posts are more easily editable by all users, and do not confer any reputation.

That is not exactly what I would call a definition :D what are community wiki posts? Every answer to a question is a community wiki post? Or only some of them with particular characteristics? And moreover, is it me that don't get it, or should the answer I posted be clearer?

Comment: See [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740) on [meta.se]

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now... but I still believe the page I linked should be a bit changed

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have a specific proposal how to change that page, I'd suggest to post it on [meta.se], since that change would affect all Stack Exchange sites (these texts are identical on all of them).